# SSRS: diagram, possible to add total/sum bar?

Tags: reporting-services

I've got a list of data. For example:

```
2014/01/01, Wednesday, sunny
2014/01/02, Thursday, sunny
2014/02/03, Friday, rainy
and so on...
```

Now in a tablix I group this by weekdays and weather and i get something like:

```
        monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
sunny     60%    30%      20%       80%     60%     70%     100%
rainy     40%    70%      80%       20%     40%     80%     0%
```

Then, it is possible to add a total column like:

```
        monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday   all days
sunny     60%    30%      20%       80%     60%     70%     100%     52%
rainy     40%    70%      80%       20%     40%     80%     0%       48%
```

Now, I can display the same numbers in a diagram with bars adding up to 100% for each weekday. But I am not getting a total bar in a diagram (all days column)! Is this somehow possible? (Should work like in a tablix but in diagrams)

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click on Column Group and select Add Total (See image below)

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's for a tablix. But I need the same for a diagram.

Comment: Sorry .. Misread your question. I don't know of a way except to pre-process the data and then display in the diagram

Comment: Thanks. Yes, thought of that. Or I could use a second diagram including just one bar displaying the sum. But the both are not clean solutions.